# TypeError at / object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, django, postgresql, async-await

Code doesn't run after running it in the venv. I use django for backend, vue for frontend and tailwind for css. Error goes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\docto\OneDrive\Desktop\bms\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\docto\OneDrive\Desktop\bms\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\whitenoise\middleware.py", line 124, in __call__
    return self.get_response(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\docto\OneDrive\Desktop\bms\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 240, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\docto\OneDrive\Desktop\bms\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 306, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: object HttpResponse can't be used in 'await' expression
```

TypeError Message:

[image: TypeError Message]

Code which the error was raised:

```
class LandingPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'public_pages/landing.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        seasons = Season.seasons.all()[:2]
        self.is_landing = 'active'
        self.previous_season = seasons[1] if seasons.count == 2 else seasons.first()
        self.season = seasons.first()
        self.main_image = MainImage.images.all().first()
        self.news = News.images.all().first()
        self.unupdated_accounts = get_activation_requests().first()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {'self': self}
```

Tried searching for the await expressions, checked the middlewares, even the whitenoise. Didn't find anything